# Reducing allocation and GC while frequently iterating through Dictionary

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, foreach, garbage-collection

**Context:** I'm using Unity3D's [IMGUI](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/GUIScriptingGuide.html) where `OnGUI{}` method is being called/update VERY often (few times per frame) to keep GUI content relevant. I need to iterate through Dictionary with data and display said data, but because I also will be **making changes to Dictionary content** (Add/Remove) I have to iterate through separate List/Array/whatever.
So in other words right now I have:

```
foreach (string line in new List<string>(this.myDic.Keys))
{
 //fill GUI
 //edit Dictionary content if needed
}
```

The problem here is that it allocates short-lived List multiple time per frame, thousands and thousands times per second and insane amount in general, producing GC. What I want is to avoid this allocation by reusing the same List I initialize at the start. However, another issue came up:

```
tempList.Clear();
foreach (KeyValuePair<string,string> pair in myDic)
{
 tempList.Add(pair.key)
}
var j = tempList.Count;
for (int i = 0; i < j; i++)
{
 //fill GUI
 //edit Dictionary content if needed
}
```

As you can see now I basically have two loops, both processing same amount of data. **Which leads me to the question:** is it moot point here trying to optimize the allocation issue here with reusable List? Or may be even if it looks scary the double-loop variant still better solution?

*P.S. Yes, I know, best option would be switch from IMGUI but right now I'm kinda limited to it.*

Comment: Not sure about your code, but the second part, you could just loop on the `myDic`, for sample: `for (int i = 0; i < myDic.Count; i++)` instead of add on `tempList´ and just use the `count` property for `j` variable.

Comment: I can't loop through Dictionary if I want to modify it, I mentioned it explicitly in the question body. I also need to populate tempList with actual/relevant content (keys), through which I'm gonna iterate.

Comment: Do you have any benchmarks that are telling you what generation (0, 1 or 2) garbage collection is happening?

Comment: I met Unity and C# 2 weeks ago, unfortunately I don't even know how to benchmark this and I'm not using "normal default" tools to do codework here so it is probably pretty ogre here with the answer to your question. I do know for sure though that variant 1 is gonna generate quite a bunch of 
 GC, had a good read today through thousands of google results.

Comment: I don't see why you have to new'up a `List` at all, you should be able to enumerate the `Dictionary` without issues if you're not running multiple-threads.

Comment: I **cannot** iterate through dictionary if I'm planning to modify its content inside the iteration loop. It is not my code, it is the limitation of foreach/enumerator for Dictionary. But because **I need to modify said Dictionary** i have to iterate through separate copy dict.keys (array/list) which will not cause **out of sync exception**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, the only object you allocate by calling `new List<string>(this.myDic.Keys)` (or `this.myDic.Keys.ToArray()` alternatively) is an array containing references to already existing objects (strings in your case). So, the GC collects only one object when the scope ends.

The size of that object is about equal to objectCount*referenceSize. The reference size depends on the selected platform: 32bit or 64bit.

Speaking formally, you can save some memory traffic by reusing an existing list, but I guess it's not worth it.

Anyway, if you're up to do that, please note that your approach to refilling the list isn't optimal. I suggest you using `.AddRange` (it internally uses `Array.Copy`).

```
tempList.Clear();
tempList.AddRange(myDic.Keys)
foreach (key in tempList) { ... } //replace with 'for' if you also want to avoid allocation of an iterator
```

Most likely it's a premature optimization, please do some performance benchmark to test if it makes any sense for your application.

Comment: Any chance for an example with Array.Copy applicable to my case?

Comment: @Digika I read `List<>` code and modified the answer, you can use `.InsertRange()` as well. Now I think it would be easier since you don't have to worry about length changes. Also please note, that if you use the `Dictionary` enumerator returning `KeyValuePair<,>` it automatically generates the memory pressure you wanted to avoid (it creates a new `KeyValuePair<,>` for each pair), so you have to stick with copying `Keys`, not pairs

Comment: Are you suggesting to replace list with array? As far as I know array's aren't really easily resizeable or even properly clearable so I'm not sure how it is better. Unless you mean some way of using array.copy to list..?

Comment: Modified once again to make it clearer. Initially I suggested that, but soon understood that most likely your dictionary's size varies and using an array is really inconvenient (of course, you're totally right that it isn't resizable). So, I suggest using a `List<>` with `.Clear()` and `.AddRange()`.

Comment: But most importantly I suggest to check whether it produces any benefit in comparison with `foreach (var key in dict.Keys.ToArray())` in your usecase :-) Why do you think that memory traffic is an issue?

Comment: Honestly, that is a good question. May be it isn't, as I mentioned before I don't really use "normal" tools to do codework so I don't think I can easily measure it, but regardless, allocating new local List andusing foreach ([especially in case with my Unity 5.4.x](https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/is-there-a-better-and-cleaner-way-then-foreach-c.451228/#post-2924273))DOES generates GC, multiple it by how often I call it `OnGUI` and it is pretty ogre. So I wanted to avoid unnec. allocations and do less foreach'es. Not sure if your suggestion is better but marked as an answer since best so far.

Comment: I checked this suggestion using dotMemory profiler, it reliably avoids allocations as you wanted. I will not judge it in context of Unity, because I have never worked with it, so I don't know whether it's needed to call that method so often or not :-)